# Android Model-View-Presenter(MVP) How to Return Long-Running AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mvp

I am somewhat new to `Android`, and I am writing an app. I am getting to the point where I am starting to more thoroughly test my code, and therefore, I would like to implement the MVP design strategy since it adds more testable layers to the code. One of the supposed benefits of using MVP that I can not seem to understand is how it helps with running `AsyncTasks` as they are performed dynamically. Since you want to avoid any `Android` specific components in your `Presenter` class, how are you supposed to reference the `Activity` that utilizes the `AsyncTasks`? Tutorials about MVP show the `Presenter` object having methods that take in an `Activity` as a parameter and return to it; however, if your `AsyncTask` takes a long time and your `Activity` has been destroyed through something such as rotation change, how do you return to the proper `Activity`? I currently store my `AsyncTask` in a `Fragment` so that it is saved on Orientation Change. I am having a hard time finding a workaround that implements the MVP practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, there isn't much you can do to avoid passing Android classes to your Presenter class. But instead of passing the Android object as a parameter, add a method to your View class that returns it (e.g. `getActivity()`).

That said, I strongly suggest you use a `Loader` instead of an `AsyncTask`. `Loaders` were designed specifically for your use-case. They can also run in the background but their lifecycle is tied to the lifecycle of an `Activity` or `Fragment`.

If you switch to `Loaders`, add a method like `getLoaderManager()` to your View interface.

Comment: Thank You for the response! I am wondering if I wanted to make the AsyncTask/Loader functionality that would be performed in the Loader instead in the Presenter, how would you reference the Activity after an orientation change. For example, I do not believe the Presenter would be Parcelable or Serializable, and therefore I do not believe maintaining a reference from the Activity to the Presenter would be possible after onDestroy(), and I do not think it would be possible for the Presenter to know what Activity will become of the onDestroy() method.

Comment: @Barry Fruitman - you can avoid passing Android classes to the Presenter by passing abstractions instead. for example, make the Presenter dependent upon a View interface as opposed to an explicit `Activity` instance, and have the relevant `Activity` implement that interface. also, i stopped using them long ago (so please correct me if the underlying implementation has been updated), but `Loader`s aren't tied to the lifecycle of an `Activity`/`Fragment`. hitting the Home button or performing an orientation change would not stop the Loader's background thread from doing its work.

Comment: @James The MVP pattern I always used was for the View to construct and retain the Presenter, not the other way around. The View then registers itself with the Presenter (e.g. Presenter.setView()) and deregisters itself when it's destroyed.

That said, the solution you're looking for is to *not* destroy the Activity on orientation change. You should be able to find how to do that pretty easily with a Google or SO search.

Comment: @James Please consider marking this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If I dont miss-understand your question, your are trying to use `retained non-UI fragment` for `long-runing task`, right?
Here is my suggestions in your case:

1. Make `ActivityView interface` for your `Activity`
2. Using `WeakReference<ActivityView>` to refer your activity inside your `Fragment Presenter` (to avoid memory leak issue)
3. When `Activity` re-created, try to get your `retained fragment` and reset your `Fragment Presenter`'s `ActivityView`. You can look at this [Google Example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) to know how to deal with loading data while configuration changed.

In conclusion, just use `WeakReference` to avoid memory leak issue, and try to re-set your `Presenter`'s`view` when activity is recreated